# Multiple ag-grids - setSelected to true is only working for the last grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular11

I have a for loop over an array and creating ag-grid based on the content of the array . based on data , I am preselecting the ag-gird rows ,

gridReady method

```
  onGridReady(event) {
    this.resultsArray.forEach(result => {
      result.gridOption.api = event.api;
      result.gridOption.columnApi = event.columnApi;  
    });
      event.api.forEachNode((node) => {
      if (node.data?.selected) {
        node.setSelected(true);
      }
    });
  }
```

`resultsArray` contains the data and gridoptions for each of the grid .
suppose a user deselects some rows from both the grids , and then click on reset . it should reset both grids but its only reseting last grid

reset method

```
  onReset(){
      this.resultsArray.forEach(result => {     
      result.gridOption.api.forEachNode((node) => {
      if (node.data?.selected) {
        node.setSelected(true);
      }
    });
    });
  }
```

my stackblitz demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-mtpg6q?

any suggestion on how to reset every grid , not the last grid only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the grid API in the onGridReady method. Both 'results' will have the API of the last.

**You have to change:**

Add identifier `groupName` for the `gridReady` method to know which API you want to set:

```
<!-- src/app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.html -->
<div>
    <button (click)="onReset()">Reset</button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let result of resultsArray; let resultIndex = index">
    <div>{{result.groupName}}</div>
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 80%; height: 80%;" class="ag-theme-fresh" [gridOptions]="result.gridOption"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [columnDefs]="myColumnDefs" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event, result.groupName)"
        [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [rowData]="result.data" [rowMultiSelectWithClick]="true">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Add the check within an `if`:

```
onGridReady(event, groupName) {
    this.resultsArray.forEach(result => {
      if(result.groupName == groupName) {
        result.gridOption.api = event.api;
        result.gridOption.columnApi = event.columnApi;
        result.gridOption.api.sizeColumnsToFit(); 
      }
    });
      event.api.forEachNode((node) => {
      if (node.data?.selected) {
        node.setSelected(true);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-b7uzye) project.